# Giving out printer/scanner for repair replacement and personal data cached

Tags: security, printer, scanner, secure-erase

I have a home printer/scanner (Epson XP235) that has malfunction and needs repair.
Do the scanner/printers cache any data (from printed/scanned documents) that I should make sure are wiped out before I give out the machine to a repair?

Comment: The memory is likely volatile, meaning it'll be erased when power is removed. A technician might press a specific combination of buttons to re-print the last job, but there won't be anything stored past that (and it's likely the button press will yield nothing due to the previously mentioned point). Stored print history is usually reserved for office-based laser jet printers. Using the printer control panel, is there a "print last job" option?

Comment: @spikey_richie: when you say "printer control panel" do you mean on the printer itself or in the pc?

Comment: @spikey_richie: does "re-print the last job" include scanning?

Comment: Some network printers intended for small office setups might keep logs of documents names and numbers of pages printed, but I'd be very surprised for a home printer to keep anything more than just number of pages printed. None of them will keep actual printed pages that may contain sensitive information.

Comment: If the printer keeps this information there will always be a option to wipe the data.

Comment: @Jim I mean the control panel on the printer itself. As for scanning; a similar story. If you wanted to be 100% sure, you could scan & print a blank sheet of A4, so the worst that happens is a blank piece of paper comes out (or some finger prints if the glass isn't clean).

Comment: @spikey_richie: I can not print. The printer has malfunctioned as I mentioned in the post

Comment: @Jim you said it has malfunctioned, you didn't say it won't print. The repair shop will probably print a test page from a Windows machine and sign off the job as done.

Comment: Unless the printer has a built-in hard disk, no data will be stored. The Epson XP235 doesn't, so you're safe.

Comment: I'd say you are pretty safe. kudos for asking the question, but I don't think you have anything to worry about. besides if you take it to a reputable repair shop, they will have policies that ensure protection of your data. don't deal with anyone who won't make that guarantee in writing.

Comment: @hdhondt: what is an example of a home printer that does have build in hard disk so that I know what to look out in the specs?

Comment: @FrankThomas: How do we determine "reputable" in general for repair shop? Unless it is e.g. Epson itself there are so much repair shops that besides eg google reviews I wouldn't know how to evaluate them

Comment: you could start by asking Epson themselves: https://epson.com/Support/ServiceCenterLocator

Comment: I do not think there are any "home" printers with a hard disk. If it has one, it will definitely be listed in the specs. The disk will be used for things like collating large documents, and for storing jobs to print later. And, as I said, the Epson XP235 does not have one. Here's one that does: https://www.office.xerox.com/en-us/multifunction-printers/altalink-c8100-series/specifications

Comment: @FrankThomas what about the scanning part. Is that also not caching anything?

Comment: @hdhondt: what about the scanning part. Is that also not caching anything?

Comment: Printers do not have enough non-volatile memory to store documents. In other words, when the printer is switched off, documents disappear - except, possibly, when the printer has a hard disk.